# Segue must wait for dispatch_queue to finish

Tags: objective-c, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, segue

I got a small issue.

I have a detail view with a button. When the user clicks this button, some stuff happens (parse xml, download files, ...). This happens with a dispatch_queue.

Also, when the button is clicked. The detail view segues to a table view. The table view shows the files in the NSDocumentDirectory.

The problem: my segue goes to the tableview before the tasks in the queue are done. Which results in a not-up-to-date list of files in my tableview.

So what I want is my segue to wait until the queue is done working and to show an activity indicator while the queue is working on my detail view. When the queue has finished, the segue can segue to the tableviewcontroller.

Can anyone help me?

That would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to not use a "automatic" segue. That is, link the segue from, say, the view to the new view controller rather than directly from the button.

When your button is pressed you start the background task and display a "processing" HUD.

When it's finished you would remove the HUD and "manually" perform the segue.